# Can deeper convolutional neural nets result in lesser parameters?

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, keras

I trained two convolutional neural nets in Keras. The first is net is as below

```
def VGG1(weights_path):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, nb_conv, nb_conv,
                        border_mode='valid',
                        input_shape=(1, img_rows, img_cols)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, nb_conv, nb_conv))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(nb_pool, nb_pool)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    if weights_path:
        model.load_weights(weights_path)

    return model
```

The second net

```
def VGG2(weights_path):
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, nb_conv, nb_conv, border_mode='valid', input_shape=(1, img_rows, img_cols)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, nb_conv, nb_conv))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(nb_pool, nb_pool)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Convolution2D(64, nb_conv, nb_conv, border_mode='valid'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, nb_conv, nb_conv))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(nb_pool, nb_pool)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(256))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    if weights_path:
        model.load_weights(weights_path)

    return model
```

When I call the `model.count_params()` method, the first net results in 604035 parameter and the second net results in 336387.

How is this possible? The second net is deeper and should contain more parameters. Is there any mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, deeper neural network can have less parameters.** It doesn't matter if they are CNNs. You might be confused, because in the graphical representation one tends to focus on the neurons. However, what gets learned are the weights, which are on the edges between neurons.

Besides the link to "Deep Residual Learning for image recognition" (please upvote Midos answer for that), I would like to give a toy example of a multilayer perceptron (MLP).

### Toy example: Bottleneck Features

The first MLP has an input layer of 784 neurons, two hidden layers of 2000 neurons each and an output layer of 10 neurons (short: 784:2000:2000:10). This results in a network with [image] 
neurons. Now consider a network with the architecture 784:2000:50:2000:10. This has [image] neurons.

This means adding another layer, even without reducing any of the layer, reduced the size of the network to 32% of the previous size!

Answer (score 2):

The depth of the network is not the only thing that affects its number of parameters. The number of parameters per layer has a huge effect. This means that for each convolutional layer, the size of the filter and the number of filters (features learned) would make a huge difference. Have a look at the paper of the VGG group at this link http://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1556.pdf

Also please look at the paper "[Deep Residual Learning for image recognition](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385v1.pdf)" which represents networks that have up to 152 layers i.e. 8x deeper than VGG nets while still having lower complexity.